# How do I turn this object of objects into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my object that contains 3 objects.

```
{
    "costco":
        {
            "costco_11":{"id":1, "address":"123 main"}, 
            "costco_12":{"id":2, "address":"345 Oak"},
            "costco_13":{"id":3, "address":"789 Birch"}
        }
}
```

I would like to create a single array that contains 3 objects so that I can dynamically create some ListView items in React-Native.

I would like to avoid using Lodash(Probably not needed, but I just want to make sure since I mentioned react-native)

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: More to the point, what have you tried? As well as what are you expecting?

Comment: A single array that contains 3 objects.  David, I actually found the answer out and posted it.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to create a single array that contains 3 objects

Simply get `Object.values`

```
var obj = {
     "costco":{
         "costco_11":{"id":1, "address":"123 main"}, 
         "costco_12":{"id":2, "address":"345 Oak"},
         "costco_13":{"id":3, "address":"789 Birch"}
      }
};
obj.costco = Object.values(obj.costco);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for external libs; you can do it in plain Javascript.

```
let myObj =  {"costco":{
         "costco_11":{"id":1, "address":"123 main"}, 
         "costco_12":{"id":2, "address":"345 Oak"},
         "costco_13":{"id":3, "address":"789 Birch"}
      }
};

let myArray = Object.values(myObj.costco);
```

I made a [little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xbzrzse/1/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArr = Object.keys(fakeOb).map(function(k) { return fakeOb[k]});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This is long winded with unnecessary complexity, I suggest you use @gurvinder372 's answer.